# Getting Object Names of Dymo Label

Tags: vba, dymo

Noob here just trying to speed up an annoying process at work.

I have many Dymo .label files and I'd like to get the names of the objects within it into an array. I've tried many things with Label.ObjectNames but as I say I'm only new to this and have no idea how to get this working in VBA.

This is as far as I've gotten, I'll eventually have this set up as a function for each label file:

```
Sub Main()
 Dim Label As DYMO_Label_Framework.ILabel
 Dim dymoFRAME As DYMO_Label_Framework.IFramework
 Set dymoFRAME = New DYMO_Label_Framework.Framework
 Set Label = dymoFRAME.OpenLabel("C:\Users\... ...\DetailedType4.label")
End Sub
```

If someone can show me an example and a brief explanation of how ObjectNames works I would be eternally grateful (I'm not one for stealing code without understanding it).

The labels have text fields in them, each is named by the property that needs to be inserted into that field. So I'd like to be able to extract into a normal dynamic array the names of each text field, "Project","PartNo","Description","Revision". I hope this helps –

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, can you give us a data sample to more understand what you want. What kind of array do you use ?

Comment: The labels have text fields in them, each is named by the property that needs to be inserted into that field. So I'd like to be able to extract into a normal dynamic array the names of each text field, "Project","PartNo","Description","Revision". I hope this helps

Comment: I've discovered this code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/492418b34ebc3b36e7ea

At the end it has var labelObjects = label.ObjectNames.ToList(); This is sort of what i want to do, but in VBA. Any idea how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :

Set LabelObject = Label.GetObjectNames(true)

Comment: That's great, I've just tried that and i get a compile error:    

"Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"    

Do you have any idea why this may be?

Comment: What is your code ? mark the answer valid if it's the good function for help other.

Comment: My entire code is above, I have just started it and come across this issue. do I need to set some other reference or object?

Comment: Do Set LabelObject = Label.GetObjectNames(true,false)

Comment: Thanks I managed to resolve it a different way without using "set" Thank you very much for your help